# i want to know about naming conventions of spring-data

Tags: spring, spring-data, naming-conventions

I have a question about spring-data module.

I would like to know why you should start the method with 'findXX' when you make a method to look up something.

If you don't have a document that specifies exactly why you set this naming rule, I'd like to look at the discussion history that you've conducted to determine this naming convention.

Comment: Note that there is also `getXXX` as well. I'm not sure there will be any answer to that question for the reasons behind this specific prefix (and not e.g. queryXXX/etc.).

Comment: Why, because the framework has defined it has such. There are other prefixes as well (which are explained in the Spring Data reference guide). Also when writing dedicated queries using `@Query` you can choose whatever you like.